# What is the delta of a zero coupon bond?

Tags: delta, zero-coupon

I understand that zero coupon bond changes as interest rates change. But I am unsure of how to get the delta. Say I buy a 5Y zero coupon bond with notional amount 5M USD. How do I calculate the delta? Interest rates are 2.10%.

Comment: Do you mean duration?

Answer (score 1):

The delta is (value of bond) - (value of bond if rates go up 1bp)
=5mm/(1.0210)^5 - 5mm/(1.0211)^5
=$2206

Comment: We can also use the equation $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{1+y}MacD \cdot P(y)$. Here $y=0.021$,$MacD = 5$ years since it is a ZCB, $P(y)=\frac{5,000,000}{(1+0.021)^5}$ The result, after division by 10000 to convert to "per basis point" is 2206.9